# javascript load image to div onclick

Tags: javascript

I want to display image user click from image link in a for loop to a div.

my for loop is as follows.

```
<a href='' name=my_image[i]

onclick='disp_image('link_image_url')'id=my_image[i]  class='popup-open'><img src=my_image[i] width='80' height='65'></a>;
```

and my javascript function

```
<script language=\"javascript\">


function disp_image(url){

document.getElementById('image').innerHTML ="<img src=url width='100' height='105'>";

;}

</script>


</script>
```

However it is not being load in my div content

```
<div id="image"></div>
```

can someone has an idea how can i display selected image in a div content dynamically

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
var _leng = my_image.length
  , td = "<td><a href='#url#' onclick='displaying(/image#url#)' id='/image#url#'><img src='#url#' width='80' height='65' /></a></td></tr><tr>"
  , i; 

for (i=0; i < _leng; i++) {
  str += td.replace(/#url#/g, my_image[i])
}
```

Check this example:
http://jsfiddle.net/hMfRG/

Comment: i want to display the image inside a div content

Comment: @PIONA, use your displaying function

`<script>
function displaying(url){
  document.getElementById('image').innerHTML = "<img src='"+url+'"+"width="80" height="65">”; }
</script>`

Answer (score 0):

You have mismatched quotes so the string isn't being generated properly, or at all... you probably have errors in the console.

```
str += "<td><a href='" + my_image[i] + " onclick='displaying()' id='/image" + my_image[i] + "'><img src='" + my_image[i] + "' width='80' height='65' /></a></td></tr><tr>";
```

---

You can't use these special quotes `‘’` or `”`, only use these single or double quotes `'` or `"`.

Example:

```
document.getElementById('image')
```

---

You have `displaying()` in the loop but below, its called `displayImage()`. Also, the function expects an argument which you're not supplying in the call.

Comment: can you provide me a clean solution please ?

Comment: You should make an effort, too, ya know.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the syntax highlighting of your post. You can clearly see that your quotes are all over the place. For instance, you have `src='"+url+'"`, which is wrong. You also have "smart quotes" in places. Fix the quotes and it should stop throwing syntax errors.

But most importantly, your `onclick` function calls `displaying()`, whereas the function is called `displayImage` and takes an argument.

Answer (score 0):

I've done it this way:

```
<div id="result" style="width:450px;height:296px;">
<img name="main" src="/images/image.jpg" alt="">
</div>

function change_pic(img_name,img_src) 
{
  document[img_name].src=img_src;
}
```